# Entering printer username and password

Tags: printing

I am attempting to print to a Konica Minolta Bizhub C220. It requires me to authenticate to print. In other posts I see many people who receive some sort of pop-up asking them to authenticate but this does not happen for me. Instead, the data file is sent correctly, the printer processes it, and stops before printing because it requires authentication. In Windows, there is an option to enter a username and password; is there something similar the printer properties in Ubuntu that I'm missing?

Comment: I did the answer from memory; if you have trouble I'll have to have a look tomorrow what I actually changed at work for printers with auth.

Answer (score 6):

Stop cups with `sudo service cups stop` and edit  `/etc/cups/printers.conf` with your preferred editor.At the top of the file there should be a

```
AuthInfoRequired username,password
```

Now I had some mixed results with this and with one printer I has to it out and with another I could put in a username, password. After editing start cups with `sudo service cups start` and retry printing it.

Also make sure the printer is using `ipp`.

By the way: from the "view print queue" you can also enter username and password to unlock a job by right clicking a job and pick "authentication"

Comment: I've edited the file as specified. Now it pops up a dialog box but for some reason the printer keeps reporting that there was a login error. I am certain my info is correct, and have tested it on the printer panel to make sure that I can log into it. Re. IPP, I set my device URI to http://192.168.1.199/ipp... is there anything else I need to do to ensure that it is properly configured? Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

After another couple of weeks fiddling with things I never did manage to get past the "Login Error" problem. I've given up and simply disabled user authentication on our printer... we're a small organization so it makes little difference anyways.

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` comment out for whichever sections you want to disable authentication

```
AuthType Default
Require user @SYSTEM
```

Then `sudo service cups restart`